# Index out of bound when use data binding to update many-to-many relation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have problem for updating domain that has many-to-many relation. For instance, consider these 2 simple domains.

```
class Student {
   String name
   static hasMany = [courses: Course]
}

class Course {
  String name
  static hasMany = [students: Student]
  static belongsTo = [Student]
}
```

To update student's name along with his/her courses' name, I use data binding like this:

```
def params = [
  'courses[0].id': c2.id,
  'courses[0].name': 'c11',
  'courses[1].id': c1.id,
  'courses[1].name': 'c22'
]
s1.properties = params
s1.save(flush: true)
```

However, this will cause error:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'courses[1]' of bean class [tb.Student]:
Invalid list index in property path 'courses[1]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
Index: 1, Size: 1
```

After some searching, I found that all answers suggest to use List for relation instead of Set. However, I still prefer to use Set.

Environment

- Grails: 2.2.3
- Java: 1.6.0_45
- OS: Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to clear the children list before data binding. This is the full code to test above domains. The line `s1.courses.clear()` will prevent above error.

```
def s1 = new Student(name: 's1').save(flush: true)
def s2 = new Student(name: 's2').save(flush: true)
def c1 = new Course(name: 'c1').save(flush: true)
def c2 = new Course(name: 'c2').save(flush: true)
s1.addToCourses(c1)
s1.addToCourses(c2)
s1.save(flush: true)
def params = [
  'courses[0].id': c2.id,
  'courses[0].name': 'c11',
  'courses[1].id': c1.id,
  'courses[1].name': 'c22'
]
s1.courses.clear()
s1.properties = params
s1.save(flush: true)
```

However, I still think this problem is a bug. And my solution is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

A Set isn't ordered hence it will fail if you specify an index.

If you don't want to use List, try to use SortedSet instead.

You can find more info @ (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#ormdsl) 6.5.3 Default Sort Order

Comment: I've try to use SortedSet and its error.

    org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'courses[0]' of bean class [Student]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'courses[0]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [Course : 1]